# AS3 play multy video files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, flv

I have this code for playing flv video when swf starts. How can I make it play 2 or 3 flv videos in sequence? here is the code which loads flv and plays it so I need to play two more videos after the first one automatically.

```
var vid:Video = new Video(1080, 720);
addChild(vid);

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
vid.attachNetStream(ns);

var listener:Object = new Object();
listener.onMetaData = function(evt:Object):void {};
ns.client = listener;

ns.play("Postvideo1.flv");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. NetStream `client` will help you to solve this task. More details on [onPlayStatus](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event%3aonPlayStatus)

> Establishes a listener to respond when a NetStream object has completely played a stream.

```
var listener:Object = {};
listener.onMetaData = function (meta:Object):void {
    //Video duration
    trace(meta.duration);
};
listener.onPlayStatus = function (data:Object):void {
    if (data.code == "NetStream.Play.Complete") {
        trace("Video playback is completed!");
        //Good place to initiate playback of another video
    }
}
ns.client = listener;
```